# How To Quick Fix Most Recent Problem in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Between a Code Spell Checker, grammar checking for LaTeX, or refactoring extensions for Python, I get a lot of those blue squiggly lines underneath my code, the ones where you can *Quick Fix*, by pressing `Ctrl + .`, and it opens a small menu with options to choose from. I have looking at this very popular [article](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/) about writing LaTeX in Vim, where you can have a command that *Quick Fixes* the most recent issue. Is there anyway to do this in VSCode; if yes, anyway to bind to a key binding for easy use?

Comment: Have you looked at the commands `editor.action.autoFix` and `editor.action.fixAll`, maybe a request for a command `editor.action.autoFixFirst`

Comment: All squiggles are also shown in the PROBLEMS tab, you can execute a Quickfix from there too

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022) might help.

See [issue 7512](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7512)

> Would be nice if instead of pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the quick fix, you could just press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> *two times* in a row.
>
> Then, pressing it again could move the cursor to the next (quick fixable) issue, so you could repeatedly fix everything by just pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> several times in a row.

This issue [includes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7512#issuecomment-1218770044):

> With the new code action widget, custom keybindings can be utilized to enter the top selected quickfix immediately.
>
> ```yaml
> [
>   {
>     "key": "ctrl+k",
>     "when": "CodeActionMenuVisible",
>     "command": "focusPreviousCodeAction"
>   },
>   {
>     "key": "ctrl+j",
>     "when": "CodeActionMenuVisible",
>     "command": "focusNextCodeAction"
>   },
>   {
>     "key": "ctrl+.",
>     "when": "CodeActionMenuVisible",
>     "command": "onEnterSelectCodeAction"
>   },
>  ]
> ```
>
> The latter half of this issue, regarding pressing again to move to the next error, is something we can take a look at!

This has been implemented, and released to [VSCode Insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).